# iOS Swift - searchBarCancelButtonClicked print appear in log but a func not returned

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

this is my code:

```
    extension MyViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

      // MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate
      func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
      }

      // MARK: - Cancel
      func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

      myFunc()

      print("Cancel")
      searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

      }

}
```

all is done as expected when the cancel is clicked, and the Xcode log shows the print "Cancel", but the function "myFunc" is not performed.

any idea to fix this?
thanks!

**Edit:** (for more context)

I have a button that I hide when search bar is clicked with:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "xyz") {
        self.exampleButton.alpha = 0.0
        ....
        ...
```

the function "myFunc" is as follows:

```
func myFunc(){

    self.exampleButton.alpha = 1.0

}
```

I tried also to right what I wanted like this:

```
      // MARK: - Cancel
      func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

      self.exampleButton.alpha = 1.0

      print("Cancel")
      searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

      }
```

but also didn't work.

---

my aim is to make the exampleButton appear back when the search is dismissed.

Comment: Can you add more context , myFunc ??

Comment: edited the post with context.

Comment: Can you please try to set the hidden property false before setting the alpha 1.0.

Comment: no that didn't help, also trying to use the .isHidden = true instead of alpha = 0, and then .isHidden = false, have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found what was the problem.

instead of hiding the button in:

```
  func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "xyz")
```

for it to be hidden when the search bar is clicked, I should use it in:

```
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
```

and now when I make it appear back in the search dismissal, in:

```
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
```

it works perfectly!